# Vi in MySQL for command editing

Tags: mysql

When using the MySQL command line interface, is there any way to get it to let you use `vi` command editing keys instead of `emacs`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The MySQL command line interface uses [readline](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/readline.3readline) to edit a command line.

Create a file `~/.inputrc` with the following content to use *vi mode*:

```
$if mysql
set editing-mode vi
$endif
```

Of course, if you want to use vi mode in all applications (including e.g. `bash`) that use readline, you can leave out the `$if` & `$endif ...` lines...